# Inequalities: $y \leq 3y+2 \le 8 + 2y$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I have some maths homework due in on monday, therefore I can't ask my teacher for help and the three equations I have are a bit more advanced than what sir taught us. Here is the question I'm stuck on:

$$ y \leq 3y + 2 \leq 8 + 2y $$

I would appreciate it if someone could give me a solution and/or explanation of it please. That way I don't consider it to be cheating, as I am learning not just copying!

Comment: You did not state a question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$a\leq b\leq c$ just means $a\leq b$ AND $b\leq c$.  If you solve both of these individual inequalities, then the solution to the original problem is the [intersection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_%28set_theory%29) of their solution sets .  Therefore I recommend starting by solving each of $y\leq 3y+2$ and $3y+2\leq 8+2y$.

Comment: Hi, thank for your answers everyone. I just wanted to make sure I worked the answer out right. I got that y >= -1 <= 6 ?

Comment: @Andy: You should write $-1\le y\le 6$

Comment: And just to make it clear, $-1 \leq y \leq 6$ is indeed the right answer.